# Flutter: How do I change the index displayed when I tap a button

Tags: flutter

I'm hoping someone can help me please. I'm very new to programming and I just can't figure this one out. I'm working a little game for my first project. I have a list for example ['the', 'dog', 'was', 'a', 'lab',]. I then have a container with a text widget displaying index[0] from the list; Result = "the". What would I need to do to increase the index +1 when I tap the "next" button on the same screen to display the next word in the list?.

screen
[image]

I have made the list with a text widget displaying listOne[0]. However I don't know how to increase/change the index from [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have an "index" variable then set it to 0 initially then when the user clicks on "Next", check if the length of length is not equal to "index" then setState and add one to "index".

something like:

```
 final list =['the', 'dog', 'was', 'a', 'lab',];
```

declare the index like this..

```
int index = 0;
```

then you should render:

```
Text(list[index])
```

then on your next button, you should have:

```
callback: (){
if(index < list.length){
setState(()=>index++);
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. It did crash when I got to the end of the list, but I put list.length-1 and it seems to work fine. then I added } else if (index == listOne.length - 1) { setState(() => index = 0); to reset the index.